# L1 vs L2 variance?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression

Which regularisation method L2 or L1 gives a lower variance?

$
f(w) = \sum (\hat{y}_i - y_i)^2 + \sum || \beta ||^2 \rightarrow L2
$

$
f(w) = \sum (\hat{y}_i - y_i)^2 + \sum || \beta || \rightarrow L1
$

Is it correct to say that L2 regularisation would give a lower variance in the resulting model as it penalises the weights more harshly? OR would L1 regularisation give lower variance as it enforces sparsity in the model and uses less number of features altogether? From this, is it correct to say that the method which gives lower variance would result in a higher bias?

Comment: Variance of what?